# Spring Boot cannot start server

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I am building a spring-boot service, but when I start run 'spring boot app' the server cannot start and I cannot access to localhost:8080. I research some topic but cannot find solution right now.

This is my pom file :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

when I run the application the log file console :

```
2018-10-24 23:11:51.350  INFO 5492 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on Welcomes-PC with PID 5492 (C:\Users\Welcomes\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.0.0.RELEASE\demo\target\classes started by Welcomes in C:\Users\Welcomes\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.0.0.RELEASE\demo)
2018-10-24 23:11:51.354  INFO 5492 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-10-24 23:11:51.401  INFO 5492 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@40e6dfe1: startup date [Wed Oct 24 23:11:51 ICT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-24 23:11:52.187  INFO 5492 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-10-24 23:11:52.201  INFO 5492 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.142 seconds (JVM running for 1.71)
2018-10-24 23:11:52.204  INFO 5492 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@40e6dfe1: startup date [Wed Oct 24 23:11:51 ICT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-24 23:11:52.207  INFO 5492 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

I cannot see the Tomcat initializatied with port(s) : 8080. Does I miss some steps? I'm using JDK jdk1.8.0_191

Comment: Hi, could you post your application.properties? And what is the return when you try yo access http://localhost:8080?

Comment: Could you start your app in DEBUG mode. Then share the logs

Comment: hi @L.Figueredo, the application.properties is empty. And the result return is page cannot access (default page when you don't have internet example)

Comment: Hi @EbertToribio, the log is same with my post above. The problem is when I compare with the successful log, i saw that the Tomcat not initializatied like normal way but I don't know the reason why

Comment: Have you tried to start at another port?

Comment: yes, I tried with another port ex : 8091 but it was not success

Comment: Can you upload your code at github to check it?